# Request: useful APIs for which to build ServiceConnections

Tags: discussion

I'm in the mood to build a quick service connection to some API, but have built them out for most of the major things I use (and many I don't).

The ones I currently have are:

- GitHub
- GitHub Jobs
- Google Drive
- Imgur
- PackageData.net
- StackExchange
- Qwant
- Wolfram Community

Are there any particularly useful APIs for Mathematica users to build support out for?

Comment: +1 Usually, I don't have much interest in such things, but your Stack Service connection worked nicely and I appreciate your work. My first question would be, can you make a GitHub repository that contains all these service connections in one project?

Comment: @halirutan I definitely can if you think that would be more useful than what I put [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163846/38205). At the moment they just all live on my server.

Comment: I always wanted a way to search the web by image (e.g. find duplicates of images), but I'm not sure if there's a free API for that.

Comment: @Szabolcs I’ve looked and found nothing free. I think TinEye or something was the best I found, but it’s not free

Comment: New suggestion: [House of Graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org/StartNewSearch.action).

Comment: @Szabolcs I just took a very brief look during a commute and I couldn’t see if they provided a REST API. If not that’ll slow the dev process down significantly as I’ll be working mostly with scraping and guessing request body parameters names.

Comment: @halirutan I've put a copy of my paclet server [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/GitHubServer) so that it's also accessible via GitHub. After all the Wolfram Cloud difficulties I felt this was increasingly necessary.